# Evil - don't yank with only whitespace to register

Tags: evil, copy-paste, deletion

How can I configure Emacs in Evil mode to delete an empty line (`d d`)  without copying it but still copy it when deleting a non-empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
(evil-define-operator evil-delete-without-register-if-whitespace (beg end type reg yank-handler)
  (interactive "<R><y>")
  (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "\n" "" (filter-buffer-substring beg end))))
    (if (string-match-p "^\\s-*$" text)
      (evil-delete beg end type ?_)
      (evil-delete beg end type reg yank-handler))))
```

Followed by rebinding `d` with it:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "d" #'evil-delete-without-register-if-whitespace)
```

I found this looking at [this emacs configuration](https://github.com/gilbertw1/bmacs/blob/master/bmacs.org#evil-1).

What you're asking for does not require knowledge of spacemacs. It involves [evil](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil), a package that is included in spacemacs.

Deleting in `evil` is an operator. This defines a new operator to replace the default one; the main difference being that it checks to see if what's being added to the register is whitespace. If it is it adds nothing, otherwise it adds it to the register.

To learn more about evil check out [noctuid's evil guide](https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide).

Note: that this is not *strictly* what you asked for because you spoke of not adding *empty lines* to the register while this doesn't add whitespace in general to the register (even if not a full empty line). But I suspect you'd actually find this more useful.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer! That's exactly what I was looking for! Also thank you for the references and explanations, this is super helpful for a beginner!

Comment: No problem! I'd appreciate it if you could change the title of the post. Maybe to `Evil - don't a yank with only whitespace to register` or something along those lines. `yank` is the emacs/vim term for copying. This is so that others with the same question can find it. Please also change the `spacemacs` tag to `evil` and add a `register` tag if it exists.

Comment: My bad I made a typo. I meant `Evil - don't yank with only whitespace to a register`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: FYI this seems to conflict with evil-surround and can lead to "ds*" commands not working. Is there any easy fix?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "x" 'delete-forward-char)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "X" 'delete-backward-char)
```

Explanation:

- `delete-forward/backward-char` is the function to delete something **without** yanking it to any register.
- **`Vx`**: this would select a line (**`V`**) then delete it (**`x`**) without yanking it, so it might be what you want when you delete a blank line.
- **`vexP`**: select a word (**`ve`**) and change it (**`xP`**) with content in the register **without** changing the content of the register, ie. paste the register over a word **without** changing the content of the register. This is quite usefull, for example, when you have a text `foo bar barr barr barrr` and you want to change all `bar` `barr` `barrr` to `foo`, then just yank `foo` then paste that `foo` to other words.

Logic:

- While a region is selected, then **`d`** would do the same job as original **`x`**: “delete and yank”. So, change **`x`** to “delete **without** yank” is fine, without limiting capability at all. For example, when you want to delete a line and yank it, press **`Vd`** or **`dd`**.
- If there is no region selected, then **`vd`** would delete one character and yank. Or, you can just press **`delete`** to do the same job. So, again, change **`x`** to delete **without** yank is also fine. Generally you do not need to delete and yank only one character anyway.

(sorry for my broken English)